R rvest Web Scrapping JSON Format
I'm trying to web scrape data from https://www.wheeloratings.com/tennis_wta_ratings.html. I'm already getting the exact row from where the data resides in line 367 of its code here
view-source:https://www.wheeloratings.com/tennis_wta_ratings.html
With this code, I'm listing all the "script" tags and the data is on #17. Apparently, that's JSON format, but when I use fromJSON() is still not capturing the data correctly. It says "Error: Argument 'txt' must be a JSON string, URL or file.".
Here is the code:
# Link from the web to scrap
link <- "https://www.wheeloratings.com/tennis_wta_ratings.html"

# Function from rVest package.
webpage2 <- read_html(link)

imp3 <- webpage2 %>% html_elements("script") %>% .[17] %>% fromJSON()

The format of the data after the .[17] is:
{xml_nodeset (1)}
[1] < script type="application/json" data-for="htmlwidget-43ed563fbe3ad2e07257" > {"x":{"tag":{"name":"React ...
The data is there.
Any ideas on how to correctly extract it?

Very close, insert html_text() %>% before fromJSON() to the element's text.  There is a large amount of information.  This will generate a very large list, I believe you are looking for is located here: imp3$x$tag$attribs$data

I was able to make it. I just dug into data attributes.
sss <- webpage2 %>% html_elements("script") %>% .[17] %>% html_text() %>% fromJSON()
sss2 <- sss$x$tag$attribs$data
sss3 <- as.data.frame(sss2)

